# browsing and playing audio and video files in android

Tags: android, audio, video

I am developing a project in which i need to play Audio and Video files. When audio player is clicked i should display only audio files from sdcard and play those files.

When video player is clicked i only need to display video files and play those video files.

I am using media player for playing the files.

```
 MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/f.mp3";
 mp.setDataSource(filepath);
 mp.start();
```

But My problem is,how to browse the audio/video files and set the data source dynamically when the user selects a particular file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should use MediaStore which has separate ContentProvider for audio and video

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Audio : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html

Video : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.html

Comment: Is there any tutorial for Media store

Comment: Found one sample on a external link http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/displaying-list-of-video-files-stored.html